# Best way to store front page content

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that has a customizable home page, I want to store the settings and configuration that the admin has selected in the database but I don't want to create a separate model just for the home page.

Would it be easier to create a key value pair table and then for different areas update the associated fields, or to create a custom 'homepage' model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this

--

We, and [Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description), use an `Option` model (with corresponding `options` table) for this:

[image]

```
#app/models/Option.rb
Class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
    #fields
    #id | name | value | created_at | updated_at
end
```

This will allow you to call options like this:

```
@bgcolor = Option.find_by name: "bgcolor"
@link_color = Option.find_by name: "link_color"
```

This is how we populate most of our "option" data - allowing us to keep a persistent data store

Comment: this is a very elegant and clean way of storing the settings. Thanks